# Lower bound of the index of a subgroup of a non abelian simple group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a simple , non abelian group . Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that $[G:H] < \infty$ . Show that: $[G:H] \ge 5$

Comment: What are your thoughts? Can you show that $[G:H]\geq 3$?

Comment: You mean *proper* subgroup.

Comment: Why are assuming that $[G:H] \lt \infty$?

Comment: @ tomasz , .. the problem appeared in a past exam with the hint "use group action".. But,I didn't get how to use Group Action to tackle this!! @ Derek Holt, since I could not proceed, I have posted the question exactly as it is in the question paper!

Comment: It's a pointless assumption, because if $|G:H| = \infty$ then it is certainly true that $|G:H| \ge 5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G$ acts by left multiplication on the left cosets modulo $H$, which gives us a homomorphism $G\to S_{[G:H]}$. This is either trivial, meaning  $H=G$ (which is excluded); or it is injective, which means that the smallest nonabelian simple group must fit in $S_{[G:H]}$.